# Continuous, non-proportional dependent variable in glmm

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, group-differences

In order to compare the mean value of a continuous, non-proportional variable `x` between four groups, I want to perform a glmm with `x` as dependent variable and the four groups as independent variable. I use geographically nested variables `z1` and `z2` as random effects.

`x` can be, for instance, annual precipitation (in mm). My attempt is something like the following:

```
library(multcomp)
library(lme4)
group.glmm <- glmer(x ~ groups + (1|z1/z2), data=my.table, family = "...")
comparison <- glht(group.glmm, linfct = mcp(groups = "Tukey"))
summary(comparison)
```

where I do not know which family to use.

I understand that `family` describes the distribution of `x` with a `link` function describing a linear relationship between `x` and ???. I do really have problems in understanding the `link`-thing and I fear, that this discapacitates me from designing a proper model.

My research question is: "are there differences [in precipiation] between the four groups?" I could use ANOVA, of course - however, I'd like to include the random effects. The glmm-approach seemed most promising to me. So I hope that someone can help with the model building.

Comment: Why use a family? To test a mean difference, just model the means with a linear-mixed model instead.

Comment: If I understood it right, I need `x` to be from a normally distributed population when modeling the means with a linear mixed model. This is not the case for all variables to test.